# Cual es la mejor manera de cargar una web?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una web similar a Mercado Libre, lo que quiero es que cargue de una manera rápida. He visto que YouTube no renderisa todo el contenido al iniciar, sino que después de cargar la pagina inserta el contenido y los datos del vídeo, después carga los vídeos relacionados. Me gustaría cargar mi web de esta manera. La pregunta sería ¿Es esto recomendable? ¿como se realiza este proceso?

Un ejemplo de como cargaría mi web normalmente:

```
 <html> 
        <head> ESTILOS</head>
        <body>
          <?php
           aquí se hace la consulta y se imprimen los productos
          ?>
          AQUÍ LOS SCRIPTS
        </body>
   </html>
```

Me recomendaron que usara AJAX para cargar el contenido, según esa recomendación, el código`introducir el código aquí` cambiaría a lo siguiente:

```
 <html> 
        <head> ESTILOS</head>
        <body>
          <plantilla html como se mostrarían los productos>
          AQUÍ LOS SCRIPTS
          AL TERMINAR DE CARGAR LA PAGINA SE HACE LA CONSULTA CON AJAX Y 
          SE IMPRIMEN LOS PRODUCTOS CON JS.
        </body>
   </html>
```

Otra opción sería hacerlo como YouTube, si se fijan en el código fuente de cualquier vídeo de YouTube y como se carga, se darán cuenta que hay un script que contiene toda la información a mostrar en la pagina en primera instancia. Me imagino que el proceso que realiza YouTube sería similar a lo siguiente:

```
<html> 
        <head> ESTILOS</head>
        <body>
          <plantilla html como se mostrarían los productos>
          <?php
           aquí se hace la consulta PERO NO se imprimen los productos
           Los datos de la consulta se pasan a JSON
          ?>

          AQUÍ LOS SCRIPTS
          AL TERMINAR DE CARGAR LA PAGINA SE IMPRIMEN LOS PRODUCTOS CON JS 
          CON LOS DATOS DEL JSON.
        </body>
   </html>
```

¿Cual de estos métodos sería mejor? ¿hay alguna alternativa?

Comment: Considero que esta pregunta se basa en opiniones y podría tener una discusión extensa según los puntos de vistas de cada quien.

Answer (score 0):

Quizás sea un poco vaga mi respuesta, pero eso tiene que ver con añadir los scripts de carga de contenido al final del código, y en vez de mostrar una barra de carga, se muestra una "plantilla" de apariencia de contenido hasta que no ha recibido la carga del contenido. Todo esto lo mejor sería hacerlo con Ajax... Facebook también empezó a implementar esa tecnología de carga dinámica para agilizar las vistas... Yo recomendaría buscar un tutorial sobre cómo utilizar ajax para cargar contenido dinámicamente y combinarlo con lo que tu dices.

Comment: Ya tengo un poco de experiencia con AJAX. ¿como me recomendarías cargar la web? Por ejemplo, en una pagina donde muestre los resultados (productos) de una búsqueda.